# How to use 16-bits Assembly inline on Delphi on Windows98?

Tags: delphi, assembly, interrupt, pascal, windows-98

Today I was playing with my old computer and trying to use 16-bits Assembly inside Delphi. It's works fine with 32-bits but I always had problem when I used interrupts. Blue Screen or Freezing, that was making me believe that's not possible to do it. I'm on Windows 98 and using Delphi 7, using this simple code.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
SysUtils, Windows;
begin
    asm
    mov ax,$0301
    mov bx,$0200
    mov cx,$0001
    xor dx,dx
    int $13
    int $20
    end;
MessageBox(0,'Okay','Okay',MB_OK);
end.
```

To "format" a diskkete on the Floppy drive. There's a way to use it on Delphi 7 without freezing and blues screens? Or Delphi only allows to use 32-bits Assembly? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In general you can't call the bios directly and bypass drivers.  Btw don't you mean $13 and $20 ?

Comment: I tried for both ways... Doesn't works.

Comment: Those interrupts are not available to 32-bit applications, which Delphi 7 produces. You may be able to use Delphi 1 (which produces 16-bit apps), which was included with Delphi 2 when it was released as well (to bridge the conversion from 16 to 32 bit). You're not going to succeed with D7.

Comment: No formatting of a diskette with a blue screen is fine for me these days :)

Comment: If you really want to format a diskette, wouldn't it be easier to just start a new process with `"format A:"`?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your application is built as "32-bit Windows" application, the interrupts cannot work since these interrupts are simply not mapped.

You could try to compile your application as a "16-bit Console" application. I don't know if Delphi supports this, but that's my best guess for getting the emulation of `int 0x13` and `int 0x10`.

By the way, shouldn't your assembly code use hexadecimal numbers, like this:?

```
mov ax, $0301
mov bx, $0200
mov cx, $0001
xor dx, dx
int $13
int $20
```

As it is now, you are probably calling interrupt $0d, which according to Ralf Brown's Interrupt List means:

> INT 0D C - IRQ5 - FIXED DISK (PC,XT), LPT2 (AT), reserved (PS/2)

Comment: Afaik only D1 supports 16-bit. FPC has some 16-bits support in trunk, but that is fairly new and raw

Comment: It doesn't works... I got the Blue Screen again. So is it impossible?

Comment: @Victor: yes, it is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 7 produces 32 bit executables. Your 16 bit assembly code is therefore not compatible with the compiler you use. 
You might have some luck with a 16 bit compiler, e.g. Turbo Pascal or Delphi 1. But it  would make more sense, I suspect, to use the Win32 API to achieve your goals.